# Block incoming mail

Tags: mail.app

I'd like to use my mail app as an outgoing service only.
I recently discovered a trojan in an incoming message and I prefer to read my messages online anyway.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Regards
/M

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best way is to leave the account enabled in mail.

1. Open **"Preferences"**.
2. Select an account.
3. In the **"Advanced"** tab for that account, turn off "Include when automatically checking for new messages".

Then, you can still send messages but it won't automatically get mail any more. Note that you can still click the check mail icon at the top of the window, and that will still initiate a manual Send/Receive.

Answer (score 0):

See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2033936?start=0&tstart=0

Here is the answer according to that thread:
To Take Offline, click on Mailbox in the menubar, and choose the second reference to Online/Offline (Online Status) -- there you can select each account separately to take Offline, but this leaves the account in the Sidebar and available to send from.